# Make Parse Data Modification Only Accessible from the Cloud

Tags: javascript, cloud, parse-platform

I am trying to create an app on Parse. That app uses data, but in order to make the data storage more secure, you would not like the clients to be able to run it. Instead, only the server should be able to modify data,

So far, I haven't seen any options as to how to achieve that, except by using user/role-based authentication, and that is something I'd rather avoid because it is the environment, not the user or role I would like to make the data access depend on.

Are there any ways to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off write access for everyone on each class, then in your Cloud Code use the master key which lets you bypass permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a beforeSave handler in Cloud Code...

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('myClassName', function(req, res) {
  if (req.master) {
    res.success();
  } else {
    res.error('Cannot change this data.');
  } 
}
```

Then only requests made using the Master Key can alter this data.

In other places in Cloud Code, you can pass this option for individual requests like this:

```
obj.save(null, { useMasterKey: true });
```

Or turn it on for actions that follow:

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
```